# FBLoginView : Crash when Facebook already login

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, loginview

I have a problem with FBLoginView on IOS. I initialized the FBLoginView and added to CustomAlertView I made myself. If shown up normally if the FBLoginView is in a login state where the FB button showing LOGIN. On the other hand, if the user already logged in and trying to show the customAlertView again it crashed when the application initializing the FBLoginView.

Does anyone have this problem before.

Comment: yes I am facing the same problem. Did you come up with any solution?